# QVTKWidgetPlugin in QT Creator 5.4

Tags: windows-7-x64, vtk, qt5.4, qvtkwidget

I'm working with QT 5.4 and VTK 6.2 but I have some problems with `QVTKWidgetPlugin`.
Specifically, I can see the QVTKWidget option in QT Designer but I don't see it in QT Creator when I work with the file `.ui`.
I copied `QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll` in `C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin` and in `C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\plugins\designer` and `QVTKWidgetPlugin.lib` in `C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\lib` but I don't know what is wrong. Help please! Thanks! :)

P.S.: I work on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to make sure that you are compiling the plugin with the same settings used to compile Qt Creator, which may not be the same as the the ones you are using (Qt version, Visual Studio version, 32/64bits).

To see this information, in Qt Creator go to Help, and select About Qt Creator. It will tell you which settings were used to compile it. For example, I downloaded Qt5.6 for VS2015 64 bits, but the included Qt Creator (v3.6.1) was compiled using Qt5.6 with VS2013 32bits. As you can see, it is not necessarily compiled using the same toolset that you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying it in

```
\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer
```

and

```
\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\QtCreator\lib\qtcreator\plugins
```

Comment: QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll and QVTKWidgetPlugin.lib are already present in these paths :(